# Running multiple threads for row matrix multiplication

Tags: java

I have a program that takes a text file that has ints in it to look like a matrix. It has 2 of these here is an example.
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1.
I have to use one single thread for each row dot matrix multiplication and then put it into the new matrix. The error I keep getting it that I get a repeat of the same thread number even though once its done the row matrix multiplication the thread should not be used again. The first part of the code is creating the new 2D array for the products of the row dot multiplication. The next set of code is the run() method doing the actual math. I do not know how to not get repeating threads to keep going. Any help is appreciated. `enter code here`

```
P = new int[x][z];
                for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < z; j++) {
                        Thread t = new Thread(new MatrixThread(A,B,P,i,j,y));
                        t.setName( "[" + i + "] [" + j + "]");
                        t.start();
                    }
                }

private static class MatrixThread implements Runnable {
        private int[][] A,B,P;
        private int row,col,y;
        
        public MatrixThread(int[][] A, int[][] B, int[][] P, int i, int j,int y) {
            this.A = A;
            this.B = B;
            this.P = P;
            this.row = i;
            this.col = j;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " starts calculating");
            for(int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                P[row][col] += A[row][i]* B[col][i];
            }
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " returns cell value " + P[row][col]);
        

        }
    }
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce (log: https://pastebin.com/rRRrgLWN) what is your output and what is your expected output?

Comment: I am supposed to name each thread when it starts and what the the number it got after doing the row dot multiplication. Then it is put into a 2D of the products each thread should be for one cell in the new 2D array P.

Comment: Yes that seems to be working, what is wrong?

Comment: The threads keep repeating the same name and they are not supposed to.

Comment: I believe it doesn't occur for me (look at my log above), does it seem ok to you or do you have different results?

Comment: I think it works I was just confused thank you for helping.